# Does SSH allow a user login without password and key?

Tags: ssh

I would like to login ssh without password and key.
I have some specific settings on the sshd_config,

```
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    AllowUsers admin
    AuthenticationMethods password
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
```

But I was still asked for password. Is there a method to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to allow anonymous or guest login and make the password empty.
here is [a topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583141/passwordless-and-keyless-ssh-guest-access) that can answer your question.

Comment: thank you. It works on my site but I tried it with different name, admin. I did "sed -i -re 's/^admin:[^:]+:/admin::/' /etc/passwd /etc/shadow". Therefore, I guess the point is an account without a password truely, not about the name, anonymous.